# Using D3.js selection.data from Scala.js

Tags: javascript, scala, d3.js, scala.js

I am new to both D3.js and Scala. I am trying to use Scala.js facade to D3.js and I want to build HTML table, as shown in example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/473f0cf66196a008cf99).

A part of the task is to join the specified array of data with the current selection. Array is two dimensional `scala.scalajs.js.Array`. Scala.js API has following:

```
  def data(): js.Array[Datum] = js.native
  def data[NewDatum](data: js.Array[NewDatum]): Update[NewDatum] = js.native
  def data[NewDatum](data: js.Array[NewDatum], key: js.ThisFunction2[Datum|NewDatum,js.UndefOr[NewDatum], Int, String]): Update[NewDatum] = js.native
  def data[NewDatum <: Datum](data: js.Array[NewDatum], key: js.Function2[Datum, Int, String]): Update[NewDatum] = js.native
  def data[NewDatum](data: DatumFunction[js.Array[NewDatum]], key: js.ThisFunction2[Datum|NewDatum,js.UndefOr[NewDatum], Int, String]): Update[NewDatum] = js.native
```

AFAIK, I should use the last method with data as `DatumFunction`, but I stuck on:

```
val cells = rows.selectAll("td")
  .data((selData: js.Array[String], i: Int, j: Int) => js.Array("1","2","3"), (d: String, i: Int) => d + "_" + i)
...
```

But this code doesn't compile. How to fix it?

Update:

There is a compiler output:

```
[error] Table.scala:56: overloaded method value data with alternatives:
[error]   [NewDatum](data: scala.scalajs.js.Function3[SelData,Int,Int,scala.scalajs.js.Array[NewDatum]], key: scala.scalajs.js.ThisFunction2[scala.scalajs.js.|[SelData,NewDatum],scala.scalajs.js.UndefOr[NewDatum],Int,String])org.singlespaced.d3js.selection.Update[NewDatum] <and>
[error]   [NewDatum <: SelData](data: scala.scalajs.js.Array[NewDatum], key: scala.scalajs.js.Function2[SelData,Int,String])org.singlespaced.d3js.selection.Update[NewDatum] <and>
[error]   [NewDatum](data: scala.scalajs.js.Array[NewDatum], key: scala.scalajs.js.ThisFunction2[scala.scalajs.js.|[SelData,NewDatum],scala.scalajs.js.UndefOr[NewDatum],Int,String])org.singlespaced.d3js.selection.Update[NewDatum] <and>
[error]   [NewDatum](data: scala.scalajs.js.Array[NewDatum])org.singlespaced.d3js.selection.Update[NewDatum] <and>
[error]   ()scala.scalajs.js.Array[SelData]
[error]  cannot be applied to ((scala.scalajs.js.Array[String], Int, Int) => scala.scalajs.js.Array[String], (String, Int) => String)
[error]     .data((selData: js.Array[String], i: Int, j: Int) => js.Array("1","2","3"), (d: String, i: Int) => d + "_" + i)
[error]      ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Update 2:

I modified code:

```
val cells = rows.selectAll("td")
  .data((d: js.Array[js.Array[String]]) => js.Array("1","2","3"), (x: Any, y: js.UndefOr[String], z: Int) => "test")
```

and compilation was successful, but now I have JS error in my console:

```
Uncaught scala.scalajs.runtime.UndefinedBehaviorError: An undefined behavior was detected: undefined is not an instance of java.lang.Integer

$throwClassCastException                                                  @ scalajsenv.js:192
$asInt                                                                    @ scalajsenv.js:620
$uI                                                                       @ scalajsenv.js:651
(anonymous function)                                                      @ Ops.scala:45
Aa.data                                                                   @ scala-js-tutorial-jsdeps.js:9209
$c_Ltutorial_webapp_Table$.drawTable__Lorg_singlespaced_d3js_Transition @ Ops.scala:45
$c_Ltutorial_webapp_Table$.main__V                                      @ Table.scala:18
$c_Ltutorial_webapp_Table$.$$js$exported$meth$main__O                    @ JSApp.scala:18
$c_Ltutorial_webapp_Table$.main                                         @ Table.scala:10
(anonymous function)                                                      @ scalajs-tutorial-fastopt.html:24
```

Comment: What is the compile error?

Comment: sjrd, I've updated my question with a compiler output

Comment: @sjrd, I've updated my question again

Comment: What code is at `Ops.scala:45`? (in `drawTable`)? The error you get now appears not to have anything to do with the `selectAll` call, does it?

Comment: @sjrd, `Ops.scala:45` is [d3 facade](https://github.com/spaced/scala-js-d3/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/singlespaced/d3js/Ops.scala). Do you think `i` or `x` is undefined now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [scala-js-d3](https://github.com/spaced/scala-js-d3). Actually, it was an issue for version 0.3.0.

Author resolve an [issue](https://github.com/spaced/scala-js-d3/issues/18) in version 0.3.1 and gave an [example](https://github.com/spaced/scala-js-d3-example-app/blob/table_data_example/src/main/scala/example/ScalaJSExample.scala) of working solution:

```
package example

import org.singlespaced.d3js.Ops._
import org.singlespaced.d3js.d3

import scala.scalajs.js

object ScalaJSExample extends js.JSApp {

  def main(): Unit = {
    /**
      * Adapted from https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data
      */

    val matrix = js.Array(
      js.Array(11975,  5871, 8916, 2868),
      js.Array( 1951, 10048, 2060, 6171),
      js.Array( 8010, 16145, 8090, 8045),
      js.Array( 1013,   990,  940, 6907)
    )

    val tr = d3.select("body").append("table").selectAll("tr")
      .data(matrix)
      .enter().append("tr")
    println("hihi")
    val td = tr.selectAll("td")
      .data( (d:js.Array[Int]) => { println(d); d; } )
      .enter().append("td")
      .text( (d:Int) => d.toString)

  }

}
```